# No route to host for the C-class external IP only

Tags: networking, routes, external, openstack, openstack-neutron

The launched VM instance on the compute node can access all the external internet websites except the C-Class IPs. The controller and compute nodes had been installed successfully according to the openstack liberty guide on ubuntu.

> [root@vm3 ~]# wget http://www.sina.com.cn Resolving www.sina.com.cn...
>   202.108.33.60 Connecting to www.sina.com.cn|202.108.33.60|:80... failed: No route to host.

However, both A-CLass and B-Class external IP can be accessed successfully:

> ```
>  [root@vm3 ~]# wget http://www.163.com
>     Resolving www.163.com... 60.207.246.98, 124.202.166.57
>     Connecting to www.163.com|60.207.246.98|:80... connected.
>     HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>     Length: unspecified [text/html]
>     Saving to: “index.html.1”
> ```

The VM's interfaces are:

> [root@vm3 ~]# ifconfig
>       eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FA:16:3E:57:1B:57
>                 inet addr:192.168.0.215  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:192.0.0.0
>                 inet6 addr: fe80::f816:3eff:fe57:1b57/64 Scope:Link
>                 UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
>                 RX packets:46213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>                 TX packets:42118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>                 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>                 RX bytes:13492902 (12.8 MiB)  TX bytes:39875879 (38.0 MiB)
>
> ```
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
>           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>           RX packets:58630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:58630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>           RX bytes:44931488 (42.8 MiB)  TX bytes:44931488 (42.8 MiB)
>
> virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:D2:F5:28  
>           inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
> ```

Routes on VM are:

> ```
>  [root@vm3 ~]# route -n
>     Kernel IP routing table
>     Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>     169.254.169.254 192.168.0.200   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
>     192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
>     192.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         192.0.0.0       U     1      0        0 eth1
>     0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
> ```

I created the public network with which the VM is launched.
The public network is 192.168.0.0/24 and private is 10.0.0.0/24.
controller: 192.168.0.12/10.0.0.11
compute: 192.168.0.10/10.0.0.31

If I add the route for 202.108.33.60 explicitly, wget can work:

route add 202.108.33.60 gw 192.168.0.1

> ```
>     [root@vm3 ~]# route -n
>     Kernel IP routing table
>     Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>     202.108.33.60   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
>     169.254.169.254 192.168.0.200   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
>     192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
>     192.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         192.0.0.0       U     1      0        0 eth1
>     0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
> ```

Does anybody know the cause or give some help on how to debug this problem? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After several days' analysis and digging, eventually I found the cause is the route entry "192.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 U 1 0 0 eth1" which will filter all the C-Class IPs as the LAN(neighbor network) and occasionally www.sina.com.cn is such a host.
After I changed it to be as below, www.sina.com.cn can be accessed.

> 192.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 U 1 0 0 eth1